# nuxt sitemap.xml not generating

Tags: http-status-code-404, sitemap, pm2, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt app and pm2 on production. I have used @nuxtjs/sitemap for sitemap. When I do `npm build` and `npm start` on my local system, it works fine. But on production mydomain/sitemap.xml gives 404. It is not generating sitemap.xml

Comment: is the file generated on your production server?

Comment: No, it's not generated. That is the main issue

Comment: are the generated files committed in your repository? or are they getting ignored? That could be the reason for it working locally but not on your server. Ideally, you need to fix your build script so that when you deploy to production the files get generated before the server is started. To keep deployments as fast as possible, you should create a new directory for each deployment and symlink your servers sites-available to this directory, and simply change the symlink and restart your server during a deployment.

Comment: sitemap.xml is neither being generated in my local system nor in production. However it is still working in local but not in production. Somehow this file  is generating on the fly on local but not in production. In production, website is loading from .nuxt fulder instead of dist.

Comment: Hi @KajalRadadia, I'm the creator of this nuxt module. Can you share your sitemap configuration from nuxt.config.js?

Comment: @NicolasPennec Thanks for reaching out. However this issue is fixed. The issue was with path of sitemap.xml in nuxt.config.js .

Comment: Hi @NicolasPennec My sitemap is working now but it is not updating after cachtime limit over. Could you please help me out what's wrong with it?  Here is my sitemap configurations.
sitemap: {
    hostname: hostname,
    path: '../static/sitemap.xml',
    gzip: true,
    cacheTime:500000,
    routes() { 
      return getAppRoutes(); 
    },
}